# What is the syntax for placeholder in Scala replace regex?

Tags: regex, scala, replace, placeholder

So I could write:

```
val res = """(\d*).*""".r.replaceAllIn(s,"""\1""")
```

So far I get literal "1" instead of the captured group.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this : `$1` instead of `\1`.

Scala's Regex uses java.util.regex underneath (at least on the JVM). Now, if you look up replaceAll on Java docs, you'll see this:

> Note that backslashes () and dollar signs ($) in the replacement
>   string may cause the results to be different than if it were being
>   treated as a literal replacement string. Dollar signs may be treated
>   as references to captured subsequences as described above, and
>   backslashes are used to escape literal characters in the replacement
>   string.

Comment: Who would thought I see perlism in Scala :-) Thank you very much!